# safely escaping table names/column names

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security, pdo

I'm using PDO in php and as such can't escape table names or column names using prepared statements. Would the following be a foolproof way to implement it myself:

```
$tn = str_replace('`', '', $_REQUEST['tn']);
$column = str_replace('`', '', $_REQUEST['column']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tn ` WHERE `column` = 23";
print_r(
    $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll()
);
```

Or is there still some avenue that this can be attacked?

Comment: @Petah I need to be able to use this class after I add more tables without having to constantly be updating a whitelist

Comment: Ask the DB for a list of valid column names and cache them if two queries per request is an issue. If you are allowing users to input column names, you might need to change your database design anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dynamic white list by asking the database what columns are valid for a given database table. It's an additional sql query, but safety is good.

```
select COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_SCHEMA = :databaseName
  and TABLE_NAME = :tableName
```

Fetch the results of that and then just make sure all the dynamic column names are in the result set.

I believe views are included in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, so it should all just plain work.

Then just use backticks around the validated column names when assembling the dynamic sql(I assume you use purely ascii column names, otherwise you potentially have additional considerations).

Comment: This will cause there to be two db calls for every call. I'm looking for something that will sanitize the table and column name rather than a whitelist. I really want to know the limits of what I can let through. eg I know I can left through `a-zA-Z0-9_.` What about other chars?

Comment: You're already making mistakes(period isnt allowed, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) unless you really understand what you're doing, including a good understanding character sets and unicode, just use a whitelist and stop worrying about performance issues you don't have. Or, restrict table and col names to a length limited a-zA-Z0-9_ to make it easy to validate. Avoid unicode and non ascii characters.

Comment: Everyone keeps saying that but why? What could happen if I have something like this (waitforitwaitforit): `"``" . preg_replace('#``|--#', '', $input) . "``"` (two `` means one)

Comment: Everyone keeps saying that because they know that some things too complicated to bother with. If you want, you can google multibyte character set sql injection to get an idea of how its accomplished, but it's not likely to make much sense unless you understand multibyte encodings. A lot of the exploits are only possible under certain specific conditions.

Comment: If you're fetching a list of columns, you probably want to use a key-value cache to speed up access to it (it won't change).