# Simple Prepared statement with placeholder not working

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

So I was wondering why this prepared statment would not work

```
$makr = 'users';
$stm = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM ?");
$stm->bindparam(1, $makr);
$stm->execute();
```

I keep getting this error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dd23834_house.'users'' doesn't exist' in /nfs/c11/h05/utt/23824/domains/.../html/home.php:77 Stack trace: #0 /nfs/c11/h05/utt/23824/domains/.../html/home.php(77): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /nfs/c11/h05/utt/23824/domains/.../html/home.php on line 77
```

Yes I do have a table named Users.

I only want to grab everything from the users DB, I do NOT have a where clause in that but I also want it to be secure.

Comment: You can't bind a table/colum `FROM ?` and closed respectively.

Comment: Ok, Thanks I did not know that. I tried to find it on my own but couldnt not find a post like the one that you linked. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. You can use a safelist, in regards to a comment you left in an answer below.

Comment: I will need to look up what that is exactly cause I am not sure. Would it be something like this `function buildQuery( $get_var ) 
{
    switch($get_var)
    {
        case 1:
            $makr = 'users';
            break;
    }

    
    $stm = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM $makr");
    $stm->execute();
}`

Comment: I saw something like that on the post you linked

Comment: You don't need such a function. In reality you will never need a query like "SELECT * FROM table".

Comment: But this is reality and I do need that function. How do you think it should be written to be the most secure. What exactly is a safelist. I just keep finding things about paypal safelist scripts. The reason I need that function is because I have a table that will display all user data from that USERS table. So I do not need a where clause there.

Comment: Use the term [whitelist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887696/safely-escaping-table-names-column-names) instead of safelist.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO. What you can do is:

```
$makr = 'users';
$stm = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM $makr");
$stm->execute();
```

Comment: from a security standpoint.. Is there a risk for any kind of SQL injection or XSS there? Is it secure?

Comment: Not in the case I've shown you, there is no user input involved. If however `$makr` is user input than yes, huge risk for SQL injections.

Comment: Thank you very much Daan, Much appreciated.

Comment: @Daan Seeing I'm the only other one posting in the question, can honestly say that that downvote is not mine. I too am wondering why you received a downvote for it. Edit: ah, there's someone else in now. Guess who.

Comment: I did not downvote. I am not sure.

Comment: @Kmiles1990123 Nobody accused you.

Comment: I know, I was just letting him know it was not me either lol

Comment: I can "do the math" with an "educated guess" as to who downvoted this answer. One accepted answer +15 minus 1, well.... it's pretty obvious. Sorry, can't say anymore than I already suspect. I can say this; that person never says why a downvote.

Comment: @Daan and Fred -ii- Thank you both for the help Very appreciated.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think I know who you mean.

Comment: @Kmiles1990123 You're welcome.

Comment: @Daan *sei un biscotto molto intelligente mi amico* (you're a smart cookie my friend) ;-)